# How to add new sheet if it's not exist in python using xlwings

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, spreadsheet, xlwings

Using xlwings in python, I want to add new sheet in existing workbook. If sheet already present in the same name, It should return the sheet dataframe.

Comment: Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Buran, I have changed my format. Hope you can understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('file_path')
try:
    wb.sheets.add('sheetname')
except ValueError as V:
    print("Error:", V)
```

Comment: Can you plz below question also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60520200/how-to-set-row-height-using-python-xlwings

Answer (score 0):

I use the following helper function to add a sheet if it is not yet existing or get/activate it, in case it is already present:

```
def addActivate(wb, sheetName, template=None):
    try:
        sht = wb.sheets(sheetName).activate()
    except com_error:
        if template:
            template.sheets["Template"].api.Copy(wb.sheets.active.api)
            sht = wb.sheets["Template"].api.Name = sheetName
        else:
            sht = wb.sheets.add(sheetName)
    return sht
```

In any case, the sheet is returned. The function also allows to define the name of a sheet name to be used as template for the new sheet.