# How to set row height using Python xlwings

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlwings

I have added new sheet to existing excel sheet using Python xlwings. I want to set row height to 15 in new sheet. How can I do that.?

Comment: I don't want autofit, I want to set row height with specific number.

Comment: But I want to set **Row** height. They gave only for column width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained under [Missing Features](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html), you can always drop down to pywin32 and check out the [documentation for VBA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.rowheight).

In your case, it would work like this:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book(...)
wb.sheets[0]['1:1'].api.RowHeight = 100
```

Comment: how to mention a "sheet name"  instead of 0.

Comment: Simply use the sheet name instead of 0: `wb.sheets['Sheet1']`

Answer (score 0):

there is no way till now you can do it in xlwings but if you're okay to do it with openpyxl 
[here is the link for better understanding](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-adjusting-rows-and-columns-of-an-excel-file-using-openpyxl-module/)

```
# import openpyxl module
import openpyxl 

# Call a Workbook() function of openpyxl 
# to create a new blank Workbook object 
wb = openpyxl.Workbook() 

# Get workbook active sheet 
# from the active attribute. 
sheet = wb.active 

# writing to the specified cell 
sheet.cell(row = 1, column = 1).value = ' hello '

sheet.cell(row = 2, column = 2).value = ' everyone '

# set the height of the row 
sheet.row_dimensions[1].height = 70

# set the width of the column 
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 20

# save the file 
wb.save('dimension.xlsx')
```

Comment: But I want in xlwings. I'm using xlwings to open a file.

Comment: There is always a way, see: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/missing_features.html